# require not working inside a spec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, require

I've got an rspec test which looks something like this:

```
require 'require_all'
require_rel '../spec_helper'

describe "HtmlEntities" do
  ...some tests
end
```

And I'm invoking it from a rake task that looks like

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
Rspec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |spec|
#  spec.libs << 'lib' << 'spec'
#  spec.spec_files = FileList['spec/**/*_spec.rb']
end
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
./spec/fixers/entities_spec.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- require_all (LoadError)
    from ./spec/fixers/entities_spec.rb:1
```

I definitely have the `require_all` gem installed (I can see it in `gem list` and require it in `irb`). Does anyone know why I can't require it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `require 'rubygems'` to the top of your file that contains the rake task:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
Rspec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |spec|
spec.libs << 'lib' << 'spec'
spec.spec_files = FileList['spec/**/*_spec.rb']
end
```

this will tell ruby to include your gems so you can run them